# Representation/Effect of a delay element in the frequency domain?

Tags: frequency, remote-control

If I have a simple RC low pass filter in which the output is taken across the capacitor, with a particular cut off frequency say x Hz.

Now if I were to introduce a delay in the path of the resistor, how will the bandwidth of the LPF change? How do I visualize this delay in the frequency domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pure delay will not change the bandwidth of the filter at all. A delay in the frequency domain is a phase shift proportional to frequency.

This is explained much better in this question from the DSP stack exchange.

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/509/what-effect-does-a-delay-in-the-time-domain-have-in-the-frequency-domain

Comment: I don't know how to do the proper links for related questions. Perhaps a mod can link it properly.

Comment: Hi Austin, would a delay change the bandwidth in a closed loop system?

Comment: If you have the delayed LPF in the feedback path you will get resonant frequencies, where the delay thorough the feedback path causes one cycle of the signal to arrive at the input right when another cycle is coming in. You would get a comb filter. The LPF part would still have an effect, so I guess it would be a comb that dies off at higher frequencies.